# How to use DOJO with Symfony?

Tags: ajax

What would be the Best Way to use DOJO with Symfony 
Do I need some PHP View Helper or can I use Plain DOJO-Style-Javascript in the Views 
If there is any View Helper it normally doesnt wraps all of the Widgets so anyways have to use Plain DOJO in between

Whats best - a PHP-View-Helper or Plain DOJO ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dpDojoPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/dgDojoPlugin) for Symfony 1.1 - 1.4
The instructions on how to use it are in the readme tab.